# Optimizing font lock performance

Tags: font-lock, performance

I want to perform a variant of anchored font lock matching. I have function definitions that start with a list of names, and I want those names to be highlighted inside the function body.

I have created a function that does this and registered it as a jit-lock function with jit-lock-register, however, performance is pretty poor and scrolling lags in larger files.

- How can I measure performance? If I just time calling my function on a large file (with float-time before and after or with elp) I get wildly varying performance, it takes anything from 0.65 to 12 seconds. Is there a recommended way to benchmark font lock performance?
- Is there any difference in performance between an anchored matcher defined in font-lock-keywords and adding a function via jit-lock-register?

Edit: It seems that the variability in performance is related to garbage collection, invocations of my jit-lock function get successively slower with each invocation until garbage collection is run, at which point they get fast again.

Comment: For the first item, try the profiler.

Comment: I can (and have) used the profiler too see what parts of my code that takes time, but since performance is so inconsistent it is hard to tell whether any changes I make are an improvement or not.

Comment: Do you have some code we can test? That might help us a lot.

Comment: Although not about profiling or micro-optimizations, per se: I've found the [font-lock-studio](http://melpa.org/#/font-lock-studio) package to be another helpful tool for understanding font-lock performance. It can help the same way as any other interactive stepping debugger can help -- you might discover the execution paths are not what you expect, and that's the main performance issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about font-lock-studio, it's awesome! Doesn't help with jit-lock-functions though, but sure does with everything else.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that the wildly varying performance was related to garbage collection. Each call to the function would get slower until a garbage collection was run. With stock emacs, gc was run every couple of seconds, but I had a line in my init.el to improve startup time that set gc-cons-threshold to 20 MB, and that meant gc was run much more infrequently, causing benchmarks to report slower and slower timing until a gc was run after a couple of minutes, then times would plummet and be fast again.

After reverting to the default gc-cons-threshhold, benchmarking became easier.

I then profiled for memory with the built in profiler (`M-x profiler-start`), and discovered that calls to syntax-ppss caused the most allocations, so after some optimization to call syntax-ppss less often I achieved acceptable performance.

Using jit-lock-mode (adding a function via jit-lock-register) seems to be the easiest way to get multi line font locking to work reliably, so that was the method I chose.

Edit: After discovering that performance was still not good enough in very large buffers I spent a lot of time optimizing cpu use and allocation, measuring the performance improvements with the built in Emacs profiler (`M-x profiler-start`). However, Emacs would still stutter and hang when scrolling quickly through very large buffers. Removing the jit-lock function I registered with `jit-lock-register` would remove the stuttering and hangs, but profiling showed the jit-lock function to complete in around 8 ms which should be fast enough for smooth scrolling. Removing the call to `jit-lock-register`and instead using a regular font-lock-keywords matcher solved the issue.

TLDR: Doing this was slow and would stutter:

```
(defun my-font-lock-function (start end)
"Set faces for font-lock between START and END.")

(jit-lock-register 'my-font-lock-function)
```

Doing this was fast and would not stutter:

```
(defun my-font-lock-function (start end)
"Set faces for font-lock between START and END.")

(defun my-font-lock-matcher (limit)
    (my-font-lock-function (point) limit)
   nil)

(setq font-lock-defaults
  (list 
     ...
    ;; Note that the face specified here doesn't matter since
    ;; my-font-lock-matcher always returns nil and sets the face on
    ;; its own.
    `(my-font-lock-matcher (1 font-lock-keyword-face nil))))
```

Comment: Could you share the code you used? Your solution might help others looking to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I didn't really use any specific code, I just called syntax-ppss less. You can check out the code in question here: https://bitbucket.org/harsman/dyalog-mode/src/faba98970c7198bbbf34a4049756815d35669030/dyalog-mode.el?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default Look for `dyalog-fontify-locals`.

Comment: I guess `dyalog-fontify-locals-matcher` should be `my-font-lock-matcher` and one of the `end` should be `limit`. Anyway, really interesting discovery!

Comment: @Lindydancer: Yes thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Re: `gc-cons-threshold`, if you're messing with internal values purely to improve start-up time, I suggest you use `emacs-startup-hook` to restore them afterwards.

Comment: I also noticed that large gc thresholds cause stuttering, but I have no idea why that is happening. My system has plenty of free RAM laying around ...

Comment: HappyFace: That's a bit like saying "my neighbours throw garbage over the fence every few seconds, but my back yard is really spacious, so why does cleaning my yard take a long time if I haven't done it for ages?" -- it takes more time because there's more to collect.  If you don't let so much garbage pile up, then collecting it won't take so long.